# Why this memory block is not collected by GC

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I wrote a program trying to learn Go's GC.
I think the area where the mx variable was originally executed should not be recycled, but I found that this area is still accessible by pointer.

Is there a problem with my code?

```
func main()  {
    fnc()
}
type myStruct struct {
    P int64
    P2 int64
}
//go:noinline
func fnc()  {
    mx := &myStruct{100,2} // mx -> 0xc00001c080
    my := &myStruct{3,4}  // my -> 0xc00001c090
    oldmx := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(mx))
    mx = my
    runtime.GC()
    debug.FreeOSMemory()
    oldmxStc := (*myStruct)(unsafe.Pointer(oldmx))
    fmt.Println(oldmxStc)
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee a single GC run will free it immediately. Even if it does, there is no guarantee its memory will be released back to OS. If it's not released back, there is no guarantee the memory is cleared.

Comment: I for-loop 100 times gc with `debug.FreeOSMemory()`, it still accessible.

Comment: Please understand this: the memory manager will not release a 16-byte memory block back to the OS. That would be very inefficient. Instead it handles memory in much larger blocks, in KBs or maybe even MBs. Again: if it is not released back to the OS, it might not be cleared and may be accessible even after a million GC runs. Your example code proves nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did work after I increased the length of the array

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is based on a wrong assumption on how GC in Go works and what GC means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this block not collected by GC?

The garbage collector doesn't make any promises about what particular blocks of memory are collected and when.  The GC's objective is actually quite broad, that is **to collect garbage (inaccessible memory)**.  It does not necessarily keep your program's memory footprint as minimal as possible. As mentioned by icza, it would be very inefficient to do so.

If you want some detailed information about how the Go garbage collector works, I recommend watching some talks or reading articles by people who have worked on it.

This one is a good read from the official Go blog: https://blog.golang.org/ismmkeynote

The behaviour of the garbage collector is not defined by the language itself, and there are only some pretty vague implications made about it in the documentation of [runtime](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/).

The lack of official documentation for this kind of feature is intentional.  The maintainers want this ideal situation:

- Developers: Don't worry about the GC and just write programs
- Maintainers: Keep improving the GC to be as good as possible so developers don't have to think about it.